# UI Router Resolves - Redirect in child resolve without re-running parent resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have scoured the web for days. I understand that if you redirect ($state.go, etc) in a resolve, the transition is cancelled and all resolves run again.

But, what if I just need to prevent going to some child state. And I fetch data in the resolves that I very much don't need, nor want, to fetch again.

I can't believe this is an unusual scenario for people. If anyone has an idea, please help me get this plnkr working!

http://plnkr.co/edit/gFDcRqoPXKbD1ZZwylO9?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('posts', {
      url: "/posts",
      templateUrl: "posts-index.html",
      controller: "PostsIndexController",
      resolve: {
        posts: function(Post) {
          console.log('Hi');
          return Post.all()
        }
      },
      onEnter: function($state, posts) {
        if (posts.length > 1 && confirm("Redirect to first post?")) {
          console.log('Howdy')
          // $state.go('posts.show', { postId: 3 });
        }
      }
    })
    .state('posts.empty', {
      templateUrl: "posts-show.html",
      resolve: {
        saySomething: function($state) {
          console.log('Yo')
        }
      }
    })
    .state('posts.show', {
      url: "/:postId",
      templateUrl: "posts-show.html",
      controller: "PostsShowController",
      resolve: {
        post: function($stateParams, $q, Post) {
          console.log($stateParams);
          return Post.find($stateParams.postId)
        }
      },
      onEnter: function($stateParams, $state) {
        if ($stateParams.postId === '1') {
          console.log('Now')
          return $state.go("posts.empty")
        }
      }
    })
}]);

app.controller("PostsIndexController", function($scope, posts){
  $scope.posts = posts
})

app.controller("PostsShowController", function($scope, post){
  $scope.post = post
})

app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(evt, to, toParams, from, fromParams, error) {
    console.log(to, toParams)
    console.log(from, fromParams)
    if (error.redirectTo) {
      $state.transitionTo(error.redirectTo, error.redirectToParams);
    } else {
      // $state.go('error', {status: error.status})
    }
  })
})

app.factory('Post', function(){
  return {
    all: function() {
      return [
        { id: 1, title: "Post 1" }, 
        { id: 2, title: "Post 2" },
        { id: 3, title: "Post 3" }
      ]
    }, 
    find: function(id) {
      return _(this.all()).findWhere({id: +id})
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried adding `abstract` to the parent and all kinds of combinations of `notify`, `inherit` and `reload` in the $state.go call. It does seem like it doesn't care if the parent resolves finished successfully or not. It has to finish all the child resolves as well, otherwise the parent state is never considered "active".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a comment, went to the bathroom and thought about it some more.

Since there's no way to do it from the resolve, my suggestion (and the solution I'm using after trying it) is to do it from the controller, instead of rejecting from the resolve and trying to handle it from `$stateChangeError`, just resolve a "redirect" from the child state and perform the actual redirection from the child controller.

Yes, it's ugly but it works.