# Redirect UI-Router Transition with "reload" without refreshing resolves multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router in Angularjs, and encountered a case where I needed to redirect a certain transition to another state based on a parent resolve value.

Specifically, I have the following state structure:

```
{
  name: 'parent',
  url: '/parent',
  resolve: {
    myResolve: function() {
      return SomeExpensiveResolve();
    }
  },
}

{
  name: 'parent.child1',
  url: '/child1',
}

{
  name: 'parent.child2',
  url: '/child2',
}
```

When the app transitions to `parent.child1` when `myResolve.someCheck()`, I want to redirect to `parent.child2` instead. So,

```
$state.go('parent.child1', {}, {});
```

should end up at `parent.child2`.

In a certain scenario in `parent.child1`, I need to reload all the states and `myResolve` - this is done currently via

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: true });
```

If `myResolve.someCheck()` for the new `myResolve` evaluates to true, I want my redirect to occur, but only want to reevaluate `SomeExpensiveResolve` once.

I was handling redirection using an `onEnter` hook:

```
$transitionsProvider.onEnter({ entering: 'parent'}, (trans) => {
  const myResolve = trans.injector().get('myResolve')
  if (trans.to().name === 'parent.child1' && myResolve.someCheck()) {
    return trans.targetState().withState('parent.child2');
  }
});
```

UI-Router knows that `parent.child2` is a child of `parent`, so even though `reload: true` is still set on the new target state, I expected that `myResolve` would not get evaluated again. However, that doesn't appear to be the case. Instead, the new transition takes over completely and is treated a completely new transition, so `myResolve` is evaluated again and `SomeExpensiveResolve()` is called again.

*[UI Router Resolves - Redirect in child resolve without re-running parent resolves](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38459026/22122076) is a similar issue, but involves redirecting during the resolve itself and doesn't include 'reload'. Answers there indicate that preventing resolves from running again after redirection from a resolve is not possible, and recommend handling this inside a controller (after the transition has finished). I am hoping that my scenario is different enough that there is an alternative solution. Having to inline this logic inside the `parent` controller feels really bad, since it doesn't really have anything to do with `parent`*